# Determine if two straight lines given by parametric equations intersect

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces

Does
$[x,y,z] = [4,-3,2] + t[1,8,-3]$

intersect with

$[x,y,z] = [1,0,3] + v[4,-5,-9] ?$

**Attempt**
To find out if they intersect or not, should i find if the direction vector are scalar multiples? Clearly they are not, so that means they are not parallel and should intersect right? But the correct answer is that they do not intersect. How do you do this? Thanks!

Comment: set them equal to each other.  they intersect iff you can come up with values for t and v such that the equations will hold.

Comment: whoa how do we equate for v and t?

Comment: <4,-3,2>+t<1,8,-3>=<1,0,3>+v<4,-5,-9> iff 4+t=1+4v and -3+8t+-5v and...

Comment: if you simplify the equations you will come up with specific values for v and t (specific values unless the two lines are one and the same as they are only lines and euclid's 5th...)

Answer (score 9):

In 3 dimensions, two lines need not intersect. The two lines intersect if and only if there are real numbers $a$, $b$ such that $[4,-3,2] + a[1,8,-3] = [1,0,3] + b[4,-5,-9]$. We have the system of equations:

$$
\begin{aligned}
4+a &= 1+4b &(1) \\
-3+8a &= -5b &(2) \\
2-3a &= 3-9b &(3)
\end{aligned}
$$

$-(2)+(1)+(3)$ gives
$$
9-4a=4 \\ 
\Downarrow \\
a=5/4
$$

$(2)$ then gives

$$7 =-5b \\
\Downarrow \\
b = -7/5
$$

But in $(1)$ we then have

$$4+5/4=1-28/5$$

which is false. So no solution exists, and the lines do not intersect.

Answer (score 7):

Vector equations can be written as simultaneous equations.

Thus

```
 [x,y,z] = [4,-3,2] + t[1,8,-3]
```

becomes

```
x =  4 +  t
y = -3 + 8t
z =  2 - 3t
```

Your two lines intersect if

```
[4,-3,2] + t[1,8,-3] = [1,0,3] + v[4,-5,-9]
```

or

```
 4 +  t = 1 + 4v
-3 + 8t = 0 - 5v
 2 - 3t = 3 - 9v
```

Thus, you have 3 simultaneous equations with only 2 unknowns, so you are good to go! If you can find a solution for `t` and `v` that satisfies these equations, then the lines intersect.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$$
\vec{A} + t\,\vec{B} = \vec{C} + v\,\vec{D}\quad\imp\quad
\left\lbrace%
\begin{array}{rcrcl}\quad
B^{2}\ t & - & \vec{D}\cdot\vec{B}\ v & = & \pars{\vec{C} - \vec{A}}\cdot\vec{B}
\\
\vec{B}\cdot\vec{D}\ t & - & D^{2}\ v & = & \pars{\vec{C} - \vec{A}}\cdot\vec{D}
\end{array}\right.\tag{1}
$$
If $\ds{0 \not= -B^{2}D^{2} + \pars{\vec{B}\cdot\vec{D}}^{2}
        = -B^{2}D^{2}\sin^{2}\pars{\angle\pars{\vec{B},\vec{D}}}
        = -\pars{\vec{B} \times \vec{D}}^{2}}$ which is equivalent to:
$$
\vec{B} \not= \vec{0}\quad\mbox{and}\quad\vec{D} \not= \vec{0}\quad\mbox{and}\quad
\vec{B} \not\parallel \vec{D},
$$
we can find the pair $\pars{t,v}$  from the pair of equations $\pars{1}$.

Comment: I like the generality of this answer: the vectors are not constrained to a certain dimensionality.  Moreover, it describes the linear equations system to be solved in order to find the solution. +1

Comment: @loved.by.Jesus Thanks. You’re right.

Answer (score -1):

I think they are not on the same surface (plane).  Two vectors can be: (1) in the same surface in this case they can either (1.1) intersect (1.2) parallel (1.3) the same vector; and (2) not in the same surface.